# Map not shown using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps-api-3

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<script>
function initMap() {
    console.log('here');
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 }
    });
}
</script>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here, in my code I don't get any errors. But the map is not shown. Any reasons why?

Comment: Your "map" div doesn't have a size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code and it shows an error which is Google Maps API error: InvalidKeyMapError.

The script element that loads the API is missing the required authentication parameter. If you are using the standard Maps JavaScript API, you must use a key parameter with a valid API key. If you are a Premium Plan customer, you must use either a client parameter with your client ID or a key parameter with a valid API key.

See the guide to API keys and client IDs at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 0):

Assign a style (height/width) to your map element

```
<head>
<style>
   #map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
   }
</style>
```